# Chrome browser doesn't display <strong> tag in HTML

Tags: html, google-chrome

That's my HTML code below

`<p><strong>bold 2</strong></p>`

But it doesn't display right in my Chrome browser.

[image]

Comment: problem with Your browser: http://joxi.ru/Y2L88MFnoVyN26

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You've got a user stylesheet that changes the font. The font you picked doesn't have the correct font weights (700 for bold). Use another font or fetch all the weights of that font

Comment: Where can i found the stylesheet?

Comment: I'm not 100% sure, but this guide could help: http://www.howtogeek.com/208552/how-to-change-the-default-fonts-in-your-web-browser/ (settings > web content > customize fonts)

Comment: Oh! that really work, I think the reason is that the front i choose before doesn't support the <strong> tag.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure - why it's not working for you. I would say try writing that code again, save and reload your webpage.

I tried it and it works. See - http://jsbin.com/zasineraci/1/edit?html,output

If not, try using  instead.

Comment: It can display correctly in Firefox and also Safari too, it just can't work in Chrome:(